# Are few raspberry pi ap's same as mesh network? Will it hive me faster internet than one ap?(routrd)

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I'm doing this high school project, and I'm thinking to create mesh network. So let's say I have 4 raspberry pi, and I turn all of them into ap and route them with router.

I must have wifi access from those to any device at my home like smartphone or pc, will it work that way? Will it give me faster internet speed than 1 raspberry pi ap? Or is it not a mesh network? Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question but if you turn 4 RPi into ap then it is in infrastructure mode not in mesh mode.